# Why are spaces in the file path rendered with %2520 instead of %20?

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom content entity (service) with a 'file' field defined by:

```
$fields['file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
  ->setLabel(t('File'))
  ->setSettings([
    'file_extensions' => 'pdf',
    'file_directory' => 'sel',
    'description_field' => TRUE,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'type' => 'file',
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'file',
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

A classic CRUD form allows me to create a service:
[image]
Lets say I upload a file with spaces in its name. As you can see if I hover the file name in the form, the link appears to be `http://jdp8:8888/sites/default/files/sel/name%20with%20spaces.pdf`with `space` replaced by `%20` and the link works:
[image]
So far, so good...

I have a View to display this content entity:
[image]
The 'file' field is rendered as a '•' with a link to the file that allows to open the content of the file (a .pdf file) in another window.
When the file name contains spaces, it is rendered as `http://jdp8:8888/sites/default/files/sel/name%2520with%2520spaces.pdf` with `%2520`instead of `%20`.
And of course the links leads to a `The requested page was not found` error.

I have recently updated Drupal to 8.9.13.
Before I was running Drupal 8.9.1 and I am pretty sure that it was working.

Any idea on what is going wrong? Is it Drupal? Is it Views?

As I suspect Views (everywhere else, it works), here is the way the file field is handled in the view:
[image]

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/16084935/2199525

Comment: I had seen this post and it helped to understand the double encoding thing but I didn't see how it can help to solve my problem.
I edited my question to add details on how the link is handled in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a kind of workaround: I wrote `{{ file__target_id|replace({'%20': " "}) }}` in the definition of 'file' field in the view.
[image]